# gnome shell crashes all the time

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I'm so normal shell crashes gnome, I can only move the mouse and I can not do anything else. I have to resort to the blackout.
Then turn on your computer appears to me that my system has a fault and apparently is in the xorg file.

Comment: does it give you an error message!? please share it ;)

Comment: The error message is about the xorg file and has to do with insurance bumblebee because clearing the energy savings and enable the nvidia longer I get.

Comment: its about, but what is it exactly?! Can't go fixing things without knowing whats broken.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-installing the Gnome shell. Boot into a Unity session and run `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell`. Beware that this also removes the Gnome tweak tool if you have that installed. Re-install the shell and everything should be back to working order.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me also just when I've entered the keyboard settings and added a second keyboard layout. I haven't seen error messages on any virtual desktop. I have a radeon hd 3450 video card, with gallium3d driver (amd discontinued support for my card in linux).